# Extracting scale bar from .tif image metadata using PIL TiffTags

Tags: python, metadata, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm new to Python, and am hoping to extract scale information from an electron microscopy (.tif) image.

When I open the file in Notepad and scroll to the bottom, I see a title "[Scan]" and an item underneath it "PixelWidth=3.10059e-010".

I'd like to read this value in Python and use it as a calibration factor for measuring physical distances within the image.

I found a promising approach using PIL (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910779/10244370) but encounter an error when running the recommended code.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS

with Image.open(imagetoanalyze) as img:
    meta_dict = {TAGS[key] : img.tag[key] for key in img.tag.iterkeys()}
```

I expected this to create an object "meta_dict" containing strings like "PixelWidth" and floats like "3.10059e-010".

Instead I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-62-4ea0187b2b49>", line 2, in <module>
    meta_dict = {TAGS[key] : img.tag[key] for key in img.tag.iterkeys()}

  File "<ipython-input-62-4ea0187b2b49>", line 2, in <dictcomp>
    meta_dict = {TAGS[key] : img.tag[key] for key in img.tag.iterkeys()}

KeyError: 34682
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are sweeping through all the tags in your image, and `TAGS`doesn't have an entry for `34682`. This doesn't mean that you can't still get out your `PixelWidth` tag, since that missing tag may not be relevant to you. You can use `TAGS.get(key)` instead of `TAGS[key]` to avoid crashing on the unfound key, and use a loop like shown below to determine which value to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your file could be a FEI SEM TIFF, which contains INI like metadata in TIFF tag 34682.

Try using [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/):

```
import tifffile
with tifffile.TiffFile('FEI_SEM.tif') as tif:
    print(tif.fei_metadata['Scan']['PixelWidth'])
```

Comment: I'd also like to extract the same calibration factor from images collected on a Zeiss microscope. In this case, opening the .tif file in Notepad shows no readable text. 

I'm hoping for a simple modification to pull the equivalent of PixelWidth from a Zeiss image. Looking through the tifffile.py webpage, it looks like "tif.sem_metadata[...]" might be the way to do this. 

To start, I tried: 
with tifffile.TiffFile(imagetoanalyze) as tif:
    metadata = tif.sem_metadata"

This creates an object "metadata" with Type "NoneType" and Size of 1. Any idea how to view/pull the Zeiss metadata?

Comment: Please share the file. If `sem_metadata` returns None, the file is not recognized as a Zeiss SEM image.

Comment: My mistake: `sem_metadata` does in fact pull the image metadata. It looks like the first Zeiss image I tried to extract metadata from may have been saved without any. For other files, `sem_metadata` works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using PIL, I think it would be clearer to use a for loop to set up your dictionary, and then print the desired result.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS


with Image.open(imagetoanalyze) as img:
    meta_dict = {}
    for key in img.tag:      # don't really need iterkeys in this context
        meta_dict[TAGS.get(key,'missing')] = img.tag[key]

# Now you can print your desired unit:

print meta_dict["PixelWidth"]
```

---

If you only need one value, you could also look up the number for the `PixelWidth` tag with this:

```
for k in img.tag:
     print k,TAGS.get(k,'missing')
```

And then just print `img.tag[<thatnumber>]` without populating the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! This eliminated "KeyError: 34682" but gave me a "meta_dict" object with only ~10% of available metadata values callable by their individual keys. The remaining 90% can be found by found in meta_dict['missing'], in a large block of text separated by "\r\"s.

Comment: The desired "PixelWidth" key happens to be buried in this meta_dict['missing'] text.

Comment: Bummer. Glad the `tifffile` solution worked for you.

Comment: I've also had success with `exiftool` for general image metadata extraction, including EM scale types.