# Loosing Geospatial information in a .tif image

Tags: python, geospatial, tiff

I have never worked with TIF images, I have a specific problem definition where I need to work on satellite raster in .TIF format, which I need to upload on Google Earth Engine.
But when I convert image into Numpy array to apply some Image Processing techniques it looses its Georeferencing. Is there any way of preserving that in Output Image?

```
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
ImagenTotal = numpy.asarray(Image.open('Well/newnew3.tif'))

imshow(ImagenTotal[10:-10,10:-10,:])

pylab.savefig('foo{}.tif'.)
```

Comment: You could use [GDAL](https://gdal.org/python/) to work with geospatial rasters in Python. I believe the question is too broad to fit StackOverflow. Essentially you are asking for an introduction to spatial data processing.

Comment: You could [save the relevant metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910779/10987432) from the `.tif` before manipulating it.