# Reading metadata of TIFF image in Python

Tags: python, image, metadata, tiff, scikit-image

I'm analyzing electron microscopy images currently and when I open the TIFF images in a text editor there are several hundred rows of image information such as the Image Pixel Size accounting for the magnification (Row 1347) before the actual pixel gray values begin. I don't have trouble loading the image as a numpy array with skimage.imread but I haven't found a way to access the information before that in python. I have tried PIL and exifread but could not get it to work. Maybe someone knows how to read TIFF images "as text". You can find an exemplary image here:

[Exemplary TIFF Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JNgb0N7Z4uXai7R584r55Ko3j1cxnc9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading tiff image metadata in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477712/reading-tiff-image-metadata-in-python)

Comment: I've tried these solutions already but could not get them to work unfortunately

Comment: Maybe you should show a [mre] of what doesn't work.

Comment: [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile) has a parser for SEM metadata: `py -c"from tifffile import TiffFile;tif=TiffFile('FS1_b3_14.tif');print(tif.sem_metadata)"`